# Which type of meditation one can do without Guru or any special guidance to advance spiritually?

Tags: guru, meditation, kriyayoga

There are so many spiritual organisations, so many Gurus and they each teach their own practice and philosophy.

For example [Art of living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_of_Living_Foundation) teach `Sudarshan Kriya`, [Isha foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isha_Foundation) tech `Sambhavi mudra`, someone teach [`Kriya yoga`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriya_Yoga)

So many organisations, so many Gurus which leads to so many forms of [`meditation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation) and so many of philosophy.

Many organisations have commercialised Meditation also. I am not sure which one would be good for me or which one I should follow.

So which meditation or form of mediation can I do myself without any guru or organisation to advance spiritually to know my inner self or to know God or to know this whole existence?

Comment: Sambhavi is a secret practice and must not be done without Guru's guidance. Not sure about Sudarshan kriya. But Anyone without initiation or without any Guru, in my opinion should do bhakti.

Comment: First one should learn and understand how ones mind shapes up due to these practices.  Are you looking for better worldly life with these practices or you seek supreme God? Are you looking to practice and see what this gives or your real seeking is God? Analyse yourself in reality what you seek then proceed accordingly

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti: What I am looking is mentioned in my question in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

There are these three meditations which can be learnt online according to these Gurus.

1. [Isha Kriya](https://youtu.be/EwQkfoKxRvo) by Sadhguru.
2. [Hamsa Meditation](https://youtu.be/axr-v-97zGI) by Shri M.
3. [Anpana Meditation](https://youtu.be/eyM_c3wSh8s) by S N Goenka.